# Trying to automate my docker container with a bash script is giving me a OCI runtime error

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to automate some stuff in my containers. I tried to add:

```
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer \
    composer install --no-dev
```

Into my Dockerfile but it never seems to work so instead I tried to make an `sh` script:

```
docker-compose up -d --force-recreate --build
docker exec -it -u root $(docker ps --format '{{ .Names }}'|grep php) "curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer"
```

However, I get this error:

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer": stat curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer: no such file or directory: unknown
```

If I try:

```
docker exec -u root $(docker ps --format '{{ .Names }}'|grep php) ls
```

It works fine, and if I:

```
docker exec -it -u root $(docker ps --format '{{ .Names }}'|grep php) /bin/bash
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

It works fine...

Any ideas on why this happens and how to achieve this?

I have tried to change it to `"/bin/bash -c 'curl .....'"` but same error.

Full file (I originally had the `$(docker ps ...)` as a variable `$container` but I thought that was the issue at first so copy+pasted it):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "[+] Fetching remote files..."
cd src
git reset --hard origin/master
cd ..
echo "[+] Rebuilding containers..."
docker-compose up -d --force-recreate --build
echo "[i] Got $(docker ps --format '{{ .Names }}'|grep php) After Rebuild..."
echo "[+] Installing Dependencies Via Composer..."
docker exec -u root $(docker ps --format '{{ .Names }}'|grep php) "/bin/bash -c 'curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer'"
docker exec -u root $(docker ps --format '{{ .Names }}'|grep php) "/bin/bash -c 'composer install --no-dev'"
echo "[+] Installing NPM/NodeJS Via NVM..."
docker exec -u root $(docker ps --format '{{ .Names }}'|grep php) "/bin/bash -c 'curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh|bash && source ~/.profile && nvm install 12.18.3'"
echo "[+] Migrating And Running NPM Tasks..."
docker exec -u root $(docker ps --format '{{ .Names }}'|grep php) "/bin/bash -c 'php artisan migrate --force && npm run dev'"
echo "[+] Cleaning Config And Permissions..."
docker exec -u root $(docker ps --format '{{ .Names }}'|grep php) "/bin/bash -c 'php artisan config:clear && chown -R nginx:nginx .'"
echo "[+] Finished...."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first sight, the crux of the issue is just a problem of "quoting".

To be more precise, your first attempt

```sh
docker exec -it -u root $(docker ps --format '{{ .Names }}'|grep php) "curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer"
```

can't work because the whole command string is passed as a single argument here… while this first argument should just be the program binary to execute.

In other words, it's as if we'd run in a shell:

```sh
$ "echo ok"
→ bash: echo ok: command not found
```

Next,

```sh
docker exec -it -u root $(docker ps --format '{{ .Names }}'|grep php) "/bin/bash -c 'curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer'"
```

can't work either, but this latter idea is on the good track!

More precisely, you may want to try

```sh
docker exec -it -u root $(docker ps --format '{{ .Names }}'|grep php) /bin/bash -c 'curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer'
```

(without the surroundings double-quotes), meaning that it runs the `/bin/bash` program, with `-c` as its first argument, and `curl …` as its second argument.

### As an aside

Since your aim is to write a script to run several commands in the same container(s), launched by `docker-compose`, you may want to:

- Factor-out the occurrences of `$(docker ps --format '{{ .Names }}'|grep php)` in the script, e.g.:

  ```sh
  container=$(docker ps --format '{{ .Names }}'|grep php)
  # assuming you get only 1 container name in this string (to be checked, maybe)
  echo "[i] Got $container After Rebuild..."
  docker exec -u root "$container" /bin/bash -c 'command...'
  ```
- Or maybe, instead, rely on the name of your services as specified in the `docker-compose.yml`, and just use [`docker-compose exec`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/exec/) instead of `docker exec`?
  I mean, assuming the `docker-compose.yml` looks like

  ```yaml
  services:
    backend1:
      build: .
      ...
  ```

  you could rely on this phrasing in your script:
  `docker-compose exec backend1 /bin/bash -c 'command...'`

Comment: I knew the command had to be encapsulated in a string so the `|` pipe did not do it on the host machine, I had no clue you did not have to quote the `/bin/bash -c`. Thanks for the explanation, this means a lot!

Comment: Nice site notes! The project is open-sourced I cannot assume people will not rename things so I'm building the script more generic. I still don't understand why it doesn't work in the Dockerfile itself but again, I appreciate the input and explanations - they help loads!